# How to output javascript string in angularjs as loop array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How to printout to html(angularjs) 'name' string as loop in the following code? 
When I printed overwrited scope array, more than one printed last string.

```
var createMarker = function (place) {
var request = {
  reference: place.reference
};
var detail = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($scope.map.control.getGMap());
detail.getDetails(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    $scope.map.markers.push({
      latitude: place.geometry.location.lat(),
      longitude: place.geometry.location.lng(),
      showWindow: false,
      name: result.name,
      phone: result.formatted_phone_number,
      website: result.website,
      html: result.html_attributions[0],
      type: result.types.toString()
    });
    $scope.$apply();


    $ionicLoading.hide();

  }

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So what do you need? Its not clear at all.

Comment: i want print this "name: result.name," as scope string. sample:  <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="m in map.markers">{{$scope}}</li>
    </ul> @Fizzix

Comment: i want print this "name: result.name," as scope string. sample: <ul> <li ng-repeat="m in map.markers">{{$scope}}</li> </ul> @mJunaidSalaat

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write `scope` in your template, you can have your name string in the repeat just by using

```
<ul> 
  <li ng-repeat="m in map.markers">
    {{m.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```